# Text in div's in HTML

Tags: css, html, text

I'm trying to set up a website to promote myself as a pianist. I'm trying to do this only with html and css, since I don't know anything about javascript/flash etc (YET). I just started html 2 days ago, so this is all new to me.

Here goes: I had this fun idea to put a set of piano-keys on top of the site to function as navigation panel. For now I just have them linked to Google.

Now I have a few questions:

- How do I insert text into the divs(keys) nicely, without the divs changing position all the time?
  I simply can't work it out.. The key just drops down for some reason.
- Am I overlooking a simpler method for positioning all the keys seperately?
  I already tried to group them, since C&F are basically the same keys, same goes for Csharp&Fsharp etc.
  I decided not to group the keys, so I can easily manage them all seperately.

Any other helpful information is also highly appreciated.

The index file looks as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Thijs Waleson, pianist in Utrecht en omgeving</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="C"><p>HOI</p></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="black-key"ID="Csharp"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="D"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="black-key"ID="Dsharp"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="E"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="F"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="black-key"ID="Fsharp"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="G"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="black-key"ID="Gsharp"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="A"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="black-key"ID="Asharp"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="B"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="C"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="black-key"ID="Csharp"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="D"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="black-key"ID="Dsharp"></div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="white-key"ID="E"></div></a>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what the CSS sheet looks like:

```
.white-key{
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 3px solid black;
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 575px;
width: 100px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 0px;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
}

.black-key{
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 3px solid black;
background-color: #000000;
height:375px;
width: 60px;
vertical-align: top;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 0px;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}

.footer{
background-color: #000000;
height: 3px;
width: auto;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

a div:hover{
background-color: grey;
}

/*Positions of the piano keys */
#C {
margin-left: -5px;
}
#Csharp {
margin-left: -50px;
}
#D {
margin-left: -25px;
}
#Dsharp {
margin-left: -25px;
}
#E {
margin-left: -50px;
}
#F {
margin-left: -5px;
}
#Fsharp{
margin-left: -50px;
}
#G{
margin-left: -25px;
}
#Gsharp{
margin-left: -37.5px;
}
#A{
margin-left: -37.5px;
}
#Asharp{
margin-left: -25px;
}
#B{
margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: [There you go...](http://jsfiddle.net/cpkp4/) You could do float:left, or display:inline i suppose... Just adjust the margins.

Comment: [Pretty much what you want, i suppose.](http://jsfiddle.net/cpkp4/2/) (click on the text - it's a link :P)

Comment: The title does not say anything real about the problem. Try changing it to one that describes what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick, thanks to Stefan Denchev

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="menu">
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="C">C</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key black"ID="Csharp">C#</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="D">D</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key black"ID="Dsharp">D#</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white nosharp"ID="E">E</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="F">F</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key black"ID="Fsharp">F#</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="G">G</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key black"ID="Gsharp">G#</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="A">A</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key black"ID="Asharp">A#</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white nosharp"ID="B">B</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="C"></div>C</a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key black"ID="Csharp">C#</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="D">D</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key black"ID="Dsharp">D#</div></a>
<a href="www.google.com"><div class="key white"ID="E">E</div></a>
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.key{
float: left;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 3px solid black;
position: relative;
text-align:center;}

.white{
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 575px;
width: 100px;
z-index: 1;
margin-left: -66px;
left:66px;}

.black{
background-color: #000000;
height:375px;
width: 60px;
z-index: 2;
left:33px;}

.nosharp{
margin-right: 66px;}

body{
width: 1100px;}

.footer{
background-color: #000000;
height: 3px;
width: auto;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;}

a div:hover{
background-color: grey;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having fixed positions for your divs in the form of pixel positions is probably not the best idea. I would suggest you have a look at CSS positioning tutorials like [this](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) one for a better idea.